# How to convert hexadecimal values to decimal values in a csv file columns

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I am trying to convert hexadecimal values to decimal values from a csv file. Here is my code

```
hex_to_int = lambda x: int(x, 16)
data_combined = data_combined[['CAN ID', 'D[0]', 'D[1]', 'D[2]', 'D[3]', 'D[4]', 'D[5]', 'D[6]', 'D[7]' ]].applymap(hex_to_int)
data_combined.head()
```

But I am getting this error: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
How can I resolve this problem?

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your hexadecimal numbers are not strings, you cannot pass an explicit base  (in your case, 16) to `int`, as the error suggests

If your numbers are on the form `0x820a`, they can simply be converted to int with `int(0x820a)`, so try change your code to

```
data_combined = data_combined[['CAN ID', 'D[0]', 'D[1]', 'D[2]', 'D[3]', 'D[4]', 'D[5]', 'D[6]', 'D[7]' ]].applymap(int)
```